# IMediaControl:Run return E_INVALIDARG

Tags: directshow

in my code, i invoke IMediaControl::Run and Pause couple times.
but sometime the function IMediaControl:Run return E_INVALIDARG, that is so wired, the run function has no argument.
can anybody help me about this;)

Comment: Is it possible you execute run or pause while the graph was not stopped or started yet? (for example call Pause when the graph is in the state "starting" - it takes some time before the graph is "started")

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, this error code is returned from one of the filters in the graph, and that's being passed back to your app via the graph manager.

Comment: sorry for response so late.
it is a problem from filter.
it seems the directx 3d is not available, but before the application started, everything is find..